# return the last max value out of multiple arrays in coffeescript

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

I am looking to find the last value out of multiple arrays passed to me in coffeescript.  I have some code that is working for similar results, but I'm having trouble putting it all together.
I have an array of values defined here.

```
  series = @_parseData {points: @get('points'), series: @get('series')}
```

This will get me the max value in series of arrays.

```
  maxvalue = Math.max(answer, (point?.y or 0)) for point in s.data for s in series
```

This will get me the last value in one array.

```
 data = series[0].data
    answer = data[data.length - 1].y
```

This will get a sum of the last values in multiple arrays.

```
answer += s.data[s.data.length - 1].y or 0 for s in series
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm having trouble with the syntax.

The values in the different series are  for numbers passed for the Y axis for a line to be on a rickshawgraph.  They should be numbers such as 200-15000.  The X axis is basically just an increment by 30 for each time the graph gets more data to be painted.

The series is passed from this ruby function.  totinarr and totoutarr are just arrays used as increment counters. totin and totout are floating point numbers being passed as data values.

```
def graphfunction( totin, totinarr, totout, totoutarr, grphname )
  if ( totinarr.last[:y] != totin) | ( totoutarr.last[:y] != totout )

    totinarr.shift
    totinarr.last[:x] += 30
    totinarr << { x: totinarr.last[:x], y: totin }

    totoutarr.last[:y] != totout
    totoutarr.shift
    totoutarr.last[:x] += 30
    totoutarr << {x: totoutarr.last[:x], y: totout }

  end
  totdata = [
    {
      name: "graph1",
      data: totinarr
    },
    {
      name: "graph2",
      data: totoutarr
    }
  ]
  send_event( grphname , series: totdata)
  return true
end
```

Comment: could you give example data? It seems like the variables aren't always referring to the same thing.

Comment: Might help if we knew what `series` looked like and what the result should be.

Comment: I added some information.  Sample data would be a series that contains X and Y values (with X just being an increments, and Y being numbered values from 0-15000).  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution.  here it is.

```
  series = @_parseData {points: @get('points'), series: @get('series')}
  answer = 0
  answer = s.data[s.data.length - 1].y for s in series when s.data[s.data.length - 1].y > answer
  values = answer
```